# The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server timed out after 60 seconds. Happens only when running through the task scheduler

Tags: powershell, selenium, task, scheduled-tasks

I'm troubleshooting an Selenium script that runs through the Task Scheduler on a Windows Server. It's running in PowerShell using version 3.0.1 of the Selenium module (found here:https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Selenium/3.0.1) with the Edge browser (the one with Chromium).

The "The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL [localhost] timed out after 60 seconds." error has been quite persistent and only appears when run through the Task Scheduler. The script runs fine when running manually through ISE.

Also to note, there's another script that is more or less the same as the one having the issue, albeit using a slightly different url (same site). This second script runs without issue through the task scheduler. They're performing the same sequence of actions which is why I'm not entirely sure why it would fail for one script but not the other.

I haven't found a suitable solution while looking at other posters facing the same issue. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Could be a conflict with localhost... the driver will probably use that as well.  Include working and non-working webdriver initialization code.

Comment: $Edge_Driver = Start-SeNewEdge
This line is not changed between the working script and the non-working one.

Comment: You'll want to troubleshoot a bit.  Try to find out the difference between working and non-working.  Since this is only happening when running through task scheduler be sure to check permissions of the services/user running the script.  If that's the same for both, you might check the localhost server's timeout periods... this is timeout sending commands to the webdriver server, OR receiving data back from...

Comment: for instance, put the "slightly different URL" from the non-working script into the working one.  See if that breaks it.  etc... control for each variable... to find what difference might be causing this.

Comment: Be sure to control for time here too... the different scripts might be failing because of the time they are run and what else is going on with the machine/server at that time.

Comment: Will start by trying a different time since it's the easiest. Will then try the URL of the working one/other swapping between scripts.

Comment: Will start by trying a different time since it's the easiest. Will then try the URL of the working one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I tried all kinds of code changes but the only step that worked for me was to change the Security Options in Task Scheduler.

Task (right-click) > Properties > General > Switch from Run whether user is logged on or not to Run only when the user is logged on.

I guess this would be a temporary solution. I'll keep looking and update this if I find a better solution.

Comment: It works that way but our policies don't allow us to leave the user logged in.